# Is there any relation between classes which use the same type variable?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

The [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) class allows one to specify reusable type variables. With Python 3.12 / [PEP 695](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-695-type-parameter-syntax), one can define a class `A`/`B` with type variable `T` like this:

```
class A[T]:
    ...

class B[T]:
    ...
```

Beforehand, with Python 3.11, you would do it like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")
class A(Generic[T]):
    ...

class B(Generic[T]):
    ...
```

For the first example, the `T` is defined in the class scope, so they do not relate to each other.
Is there any difference to the second 'old' example? Or: Is there any connection between the two classes `A` and `B`?

Comment: No, there is no such connection. `TypeVar` is declared outside of class scope, but is not interpreted as "the same" for different users. If it's bound in generic, it is the same for the whole class body, but not for any other classes outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such connection from the typechecker's POV. `TypeVar` is declared outside of class scope just because it's convenient to do so, it does not imply any relationships between its users.

Type variable is bound in the following scopes:

- Class scope - if a class inherits from `Generic` (or parametrized `Protocol`, or other generic class), type variable that parametrizes its parents is bound to class scope. All occurrences of this type variable are resolved to the same type in same context.
- Function/method scope - if a function includes a type variable as part of its parameter(s) or return type, this type variable resolves in function body to the same type as in signature.

No other binding is taking place. This is explained in detail in [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#scoping-rules-for-type-variables) (link to relevant section).

However, there may be clean semantic relationship (and it was one of my arguments against PEP695 - a battle I, unfortunately, lost). Consider [`django-stubs`](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/706f41f657bd6b92e0e4d8ec966e28d674787c6a/django-stubs/db/models/fields/__init__.pyi#L53) (permalink to the declaration):

```py
# __set__ value type
_ST = TypeVar("_ST", contravariant=True)
# __get__ return type
_GT = TypeVar("_GT", covariant=True)

class Field(RegisterLookupMixin, Generic[_ST, _GT]):
    ... # omitted (there are 150+ lines here in fact)

class IntegerField(Field[_ST, _GT]):
    ...
class PositiveIntegerRelDbTypeMixin:
    ...
class SmallIntegerField(IntegerField[_ST, _GT]): ...
class BigIntegerField(IntegerField[_ST, _GT]):
    ...
class PositiveIntegerField(PositiveIntegerRelDbTypeMixin, IntegerField[_ST, _GT]): ...
class PositiveSmallIntegerField(PositiveIntegerRelDbTypeMixin, SmallIntegerField[_ST, _GT]): ...
class PositiveBigIntegerField(PositiveIntegerRelDbTypeMixin, BigIntegerField[_ST, _GT]): ...
```

These fields do not have to resolve to the same type variables, obviously. However, `_ST` and `_GT` have a semantic meaning, which is same for all of them. This does not influence type checking, but helps those who read this code. If `_GT` and `_ST` were defined for each class separately, then, in addition to unreadable and unpleasantly looking syntax, we'd have to either repeat comments near every class or document that once in module docstring and add one extra lookup step to demystify their meaning. Using longer forms like `_SetterType` and `_GetterType` would remove need for explanation, but also make the already long-ish signatures longer. Additionally, explanation of how `Field` typing works is still necessary (there are other caveats). Now it's explained in a docstring that comes right after typevar declaration, but with PEP695 style it'd be written far away.

Comment: Well, the good news for you PEP 695 haters is that the old-style `TypeVar` can't be deprecated as long as variance can't be explicitly specified in the PEP 695 syntax. (To clarify - I don't have a strong opinion on PEP 695. I think the idea is right as other languages do it, but the execution could have been better.)

Comment: @dROOOze yeah, it can't be deprecated for this reason, and now python has two incompatible type var systems...

Comment: After seeing your comment and answer, I realized reading the motivation section of PEP695 [pep-695#points of confusion](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/#points-of-confusion)  would have helped ; ) (Specifically the first two paragraphs of "Points of Confusion")